# Setting the Text Property of a Textbox (Windows Phone 8 App)

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

Basically I want to set a textbox value equal to the CustomerName  from a card which is created for Wallet. What do I need to set the text property of textbox equal to, in order to achieve this. Is this possible? Thanks

Product.xaml (Where textbox is)

The Code

```
<TextBoxGrid.Row="1"Grid.Column="0"Name="TodoInput2"Text="{}"Visibility="Collapsed"/>
```

`Product.xaml.cs`  (Where the card for Wallet is created, I want to set my textbox equal to the value of `Pi.CustomerName=member. Name` )

The Code

```
PaymentInstrument PI;

PI = new PaymentInstrument("Account")

Pi.CustomerName = member. Name;
```

Answer (score 0):

you should set PI as the datacontext for the page or for the textbox and then you can bind to it by using

```
<TextBoxGrid.Row="1"Grid.Column="0"Name="TodoInput2"Text="{Binding CustomerName}"Visibility="Collapsed"/>
```

for setting the datacontext on the textbox or in any other element you can give the element a name and in code behind set the datacontext
for example

```
<TextBoxGrid x:Name=TxtBox>
   <TextBoxGrid.Row="1"Grid.Column="0"Name="TodoInput2"Text="{Binding CustomerName}"Visibility="Collapsed"/>
</TextBoxGrid>
```

in codebehind

```
TxtBox.DataContext=PI;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Fabio. Just one question, How would I set PI to be the datacontext for the page or textbox. Thanks

Comment: Thanks Fabio for your solution. I have tried this out and I get back an error. "The name 'TextBoxGrid' does not exist in the namespace "http://schemas.microsoft.com/client/2007".                                                                                 It seems I could be missing an assembly reference but I am not sure which one. Any ideas? Thanks